# using get_option to add a different js

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to us `get_option` in my plugin to choose to load 1 of 3 js files.

I started with this (and it works) ...

```
add_action('wp_footer','isotope_vpl_set_style');

function isotope_vpl_set_style() {
        include("inc/myfile.js");
        }
```

then I changed it to ...

```
add_action('wp_footer','isotope_vpl_set_style');  

function isotope_vpl_set_style() {   
$style = (get_option('damien_style');    
if  $style = ("isotope"){
        include("inc/myfile.js");
        }
}
```

And it's not working ... I checked the SQL table and the option name and value are set.

My PHP error log tells me I have an unexpected ; on this line `$style = (get_option('damien_style');`

Where have I gone wrong please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an extra `(` before `get_option` and the if statement syntax was wrong. Here is the revised code:

```
add_action('wp_footer','isotope_vpl_set_style');  

function isotope_vpl_set_style() {   
    $style = get_option('damien_style');    
    if($style == "isotope") {
        include("inc/myfile.js");
    }
}
```